# PHP: Class vs Instance variables

Tags: php, oop

I know there is a difference in class variables and instance variables in programming languages like Java and C#, so I was wondering if PHP is the same.

So I know class variables is shared among all the instances of that class whereas instance variables is only relevant to that specific instance of that class.

For example:

```
class db {
  private $host;   <--
  private $user;   <-- These will be treated as instance variables
  private $pass;   <-- as they are set by the class constructor
  private $dbname; <--

  private $connected = false; <-- Will this be treated as a class 
                                  variable? Shared among all the 
                                  instance of the db class?

  public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pass = $pass;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
  }

  public function checkConn() {
    // some code here to change the value of $this->connected
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has [static class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties). None of the properties in your code are declared as static, so they all are instance properties.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#59676) is exactly what I was looking for.